# No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql when trying to connect spark-shell (inside a docker container) to my PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, shell, apache-spark, docker

I'm running Spark on a docker container ([sequenceiq/spark](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark)).
I launched it like this:

```
docker run --link dbHost:dbHost  -v my/path/to/postgres/jar:postgres/ -it -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 bash
```

I'm sure that the postgreSQL database is accessible through the address `postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/ticketapp`.

I start the spark-shell with `spark-shell --jars postgres/postgresql-9.4-1205.jdbc42.jar` and since I can connect from my Play! application that has as dependency `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1205-jdbc42"` it seems that I have the correct jar. (I also don't any warning saying that the local jar does not exist.)

But when I try to connect to my database with:

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://dbHost:5432/ticketapp?user=user&password=password", 
    "dbtable" -> "events")
  ).load()
```

(I also tried the url `jdbc:postgresql://user:root@dbHost:5432/ticketapp`)

as it is explained in the spark documentation, I get this error: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://dbHost:5432/ticketapp?user=simon&password=root

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you need to include the JDBC driver for you particular database on the spark classpath. According to documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) it should be done like this:

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar bin/spark-shell
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but with the same result. And I get this warning (I'm working with Spark 1.6): `This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-class-path to augment the driver classpath
 - spark.executor.extraClassPath to augment the executor classpath`

Comment: As an option, just for testing purposes you can edit spark-env.sh and specify the path to the jar explicitly, e.g. export SPARK_CLASSPATH=<PATH TO JAR>. If that won't help, I assume that the issue is not with the classpath.

Comment: It would indeed be an option but I can't find this file on my Docker container (find / -name "spark-env" outputs nothing).

Comment: you can create one in $SPARK_HOME/conf called spark-env.sh and it will be used automatically

Comment: I created a conf/spark-env.sh in the directory where is located "spark-shell" but it doesn't seem to be taken into account since even write "lkjlk" inside does not lead to an error... There is also a load-spark-env.sh file in the $SPARK_HOME directory so I tried to add the line to it but wihout success.